# Argument error when paginating data with preloaded associations

Tags: ajax, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to paginate data that has preloaded associations.

In my controller this works:

```
  def index(conn, _params) do
    products = Product
        |> Repo.all
        |> Repo.preload(:category)

    render(conn, "index.html", products: products)
  end
```

And this also works:

```
  def index(conn, params) do
    {products, kerosene} = Product
    |> Repo.paginate(params)

    render(conn, "index.html", products: products, kerosene: kerosene)
  end
```

But combining them produces `argument error on line |> Repo.paginate(params)`

```
  def index(conn, params) do
    {products, kerosene} = Product
    |> Repo.all
    |> Repo.preload(:category)
    |> Repo.paginate(params)

    render(conn, "index.html", products: products, kerosene: kerosene)
  end
```

If I drop line `|> Repo.all` it produces:

```
no function clause matching in Ecto.Repo.Preloader.preload/4" on line |> Repo.preload(:category)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using [Kerosene](https://github.com/elixirdrops/kerosene), `Repo.paginate` expects a query as argument while `Repo.all |> Repo.paginate` returns a list of structs. You can use either `Ecto.Query.preload` or create a query using `from` with a preload attribute to generate a query which automatically preloads when it's run.

```
{products, kerosene} =
  Product
  |> Ecto.Query.preload(:category)
  |> Repo.paginate(params)

# or

{products, kerosene} =
  from(p in Product, preload: :category)
  |> Repo.paginate(params)
```